# Closure? Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures

Though there is another post about closures my question is aimed at a specific block of code in order to make sure after reading the other linked post I was correct in my thinking.

I’m at the following code in the book

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function(m) { return m > n; };
}
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
```

My question is how does the greaterThan10 function remember the value of n? Is this an example of closures?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is an example of closures.

We have an inner function, wrapped inside the outer function `greaterThan`. Now here comes the interesting thing.

We are passing value to `greaterThan(n)` as :

`var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);`

Now just imagine for a second that the value is being help in this variable `greaterThan10` i.e; 10 (assigned to first local variable 'n' in our case) .Now whenever you will use this variable and pass it a variable, it will automatically be assigned to the second local variable (`m` in our case). Now you can imagine the output which would be `true`.

You can do this deep down (three levels,four levels and so on), but the basics would be same.

Hope you understand :-)